# How do I mock only one value returned by a custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple `TodoList` component that uses a custom hook `useTodos`

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useTodos = (initialTodos = []) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(initialTodos)

  const addTodo = (value) => {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos, value]
    setTodos(updatedTodos)
  }

  const removeTodo = (index) => {
    const updatedTodos = todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index)
    setTodos(updatedTodos)
  }

  return { todos, addTodo, removeTodo }
}
```

I would like to test the component with `React Testing Library`.

In order to do so, I want to mock the initial `todos` returned by the hook.

```js
jest.mock('hooks/useTodos', () => ({
  useTodos: () => ({
    todos: ['Wake up', 'Go to work'],
  }),
}))
```

But the methods `addTodo` and `removeTodo` are then undefined. On the other hand, when I mock them with `jest.fn()` they do not work anymore.

Is there any way to mock **only `todos` and keep other methods working**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mocked `useTodos` hook with mock todos initial state based on the real `useTodos` hook.

`hooks.js`:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useTodos = (initialTodos = []) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(initialTodos);

  const addTodo = (value) => {
    const updatedTodos = [...todos, value];
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  const removeTodo = (index) => {
    const updatedTodos = todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index);
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  return { todos, addTodo, removeTodo };
};
```

`index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTodos } from './hooks';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { todos, addTodo, removeTodo } = useTodos();
  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo, i) => (
        <p key={i}>
          {todo}
          <button type="button" onClick={() => removeTodo(i)}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </p>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => addTodo('have a drink')}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import MyComponent from '.';

jest.mock('./hooks', () => {
  const { useTodos } = jest.requireActual('./hooks');
  return {
    useTodos: () => useTodos(['Wake up', 'Go to work']),
  };
});

describe('69399677', () => {
  test('should render todos', () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/Wake up/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/Go to work/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  test('should add todo', () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Add/));
    expect(screen.getByText(/have a drink/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  test('should remove todo', () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Go to work/).querySelector('button'));
    expect(screen.queryByText(/Go to work/)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69399677/index.test.jsx (8.788 s)
  69399677
    ✓ should render todos (26 ms)
    ✓ should add todo (10 ms)
    ✓ should remove todo (4 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |        0 |     100 |     100 |                   
 hooks.js  |     100 |        0 |     100 |     100 | 3                 
 index.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.406 s
```